# Is it Anti-Pattern or less performant to split render functions in a Component?

Tags: reactjs

I've seen this usage a few times surfing the web, and I haven't find any specifics on this matter.

Is it anti-pattern or does it have any performance impact to structure the components this way?

I've find this way more readable also allows me to group the variables for each part of the component

I have some performance issues, but I don't think they are related to this, so I would like to discard this topic as the responsible one.

By the way, this division is because there is no need to create an additional component for those nodes.

Breaking apart the render method like this:

```js
const MyComponent = React.createClass({

    //helper render function
    render_top(){
        const cssClass='some-class';
        return( <div className={cssClass}>topElement {this.props.someProp}</div> );
    },

    //helper render function
    render_bottom(){
        const cssClass='some-other-class';
        return( <div className={cssClass}>topElement</div> );
    },

    //Actual Render Function
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {/*... bunch of jsx code and components*/}

                { this.render_top() }    {/*<---- is it valid?*/}

                {/*... bunch of jsx code and components*/}

               { this.render_bottom() }  {/*<---- will affect performance?*/}

            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

**Update**: Would be interesting if someone can suggest a test to notice the differences.

In the react page they comment about using arrow functions `()=>{  }` in render method, that is anti pattern though, because every time the component renders, a new instance of such function will be created.

But in the same approach, **every time the render method calls a helper function ... is the returned value a new instance or it will be the same instance every time?**

I'm not sure how to test it, I'm open to all points of view, but it would be nice to have something a little more concrete to support such points of view ...

Comment: it actually works as it should,  but don't know if calling the function on each render will cause a memory leak creating a different node every time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not less performant .Its a standard to split your render functions into more meaningful blocks and prevent it from becoming too large and unreadable

Comment: isn`t it against the pure render pattern? It states that you supposed to have only props and state in render, although the splitted functions uses only props and state by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Its not anti pattern and not less performant too. Its a nice idea to split your components as [Dumb and Container Components](http://jaketrent.com/post/smart-dumb-components-react/) for better readability.

I Would suggest to have your actual render component as bellow

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            ... bunch of jsx code and components

            <TopElement />  <---- render_top()

            ... bunch of jsx code and components

            <BotomElement />     <---- render_bottom()
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: agreed on the Dumb and Smart components... but what if there is no need for extra components and the helpers are just to organise the code and improve readability.    Even on text fragments react keeps track of them to update just the sections needed, in this case ... won't be a new instance returned every time a helper is called?

Answer (score 0):

It returns a new instance each time. This stands by storing each returned value in an array and watching the contents. However there is no memory leak. They will be garbage-collected. As to performance, [React Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) is capable of comparing the instances and renders efficiently. There is overhead but little, and worth it with regards to coding structure and focus separation IMHO.